# How can i create a transparent and non rectangular NSWindow with Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I want to create a windows style error popup for my Cocoa application like this one
[image]

Is there any tutorial how to do this? Or can somebody give me at least the names of a few API functions that i need to check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass). You can configure its background and border to match.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has an example: [Round Transparent Window](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: And to staple that window to the window with the main content, add it as a child window. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/addChildWindow:ordered:

Answer (score 0):

As of 10.7, you can do this with NSPopover.

I'm not sure whether you can make one transparent, but the default appearance is consistent with how popovers are expected to look on the Mac.